# delete a row of dataframe with 2 conditions

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df1`

```
    269     270    271  346
0     1  153.00   2.14    1
1     1  153.21   3.89    2
2     1  153.90   2.02    1
3     1  154.18   3.02    1
4     1  154.47   2.30    1
5     1  154.66   2.73    1
6     1  155.35   2.82    1
7     1  155.70   2.32    1
8     1  220.00  15.50    1
9     0  152.64   1.44    1
10    0  152.04   2.20    1
11    0  150.48   1.59    1
12    0  149.88   1.73    1
13    0  129.00   0.01    1
```

and a second dataframe `df2`

```
    269      270    271  346
0     0   149.88    2.0    1
```

I would like the row at the index `12` to be remove because they have the same number in columns `['269']` & `['270']`

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'col_1': [3, 2, 1, 0], 'col_2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
print(df1)

data1 = {'col_1': [3, 2], 'col_2': ['a', 'b']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data1)
print(df2)


print(df1.loc[~((df1["col_1"].isin(df2['col_1']))&(df1["col_2"].isin(df2['col_2']))),:])
```

DF1:

```
   col_1 col_2
0      3     a
1      2     b
2      1     c
3      0     d
```

DF2:

```
   col_1 col_2
0      3     a
1      2     b
```

Output:

```
   col_1 col_2
2      1     c
3      0     d
```

In Your code Use:

```
df1.loc[~((df1["269"].isin(df2['269']))&(df1["270"].isin(df2['270']))),:]
```

Answer (score 0):

One method to solve this is to do a `inner` join on the columns you want to compare the dataframes. Then do a `loc` to find similar rows with `isin` and then drop those indices.

In codes,

```
    m = pd.merge(df1[['269', '270']], df2[['269', '270']], how='inner', on=['269', '270'])

    df1.drop(df1.loc[((df1['269'].isin(m['269'])) & (df1['270'].isin(m['270'])))].index)

#Output
    269 270 271 346
0   1   153.00  2.14    1
1   1   153.21  3.89    2
2   1   153.90  2.02    1
3   1   154.18  3.02    1
4   1   154.47  2.30    1
5   1   154.66  2.73    1
6   1   155.35  2.82    1
7   1   155.70  2.32    1
8   1   220.00  15.50   1
9   0   152.64  1.44    1
10  0   152.04  2.20    1
11  0   150.48  1.59    1
13  0   129.00  0.01    1
```